# kue - Unexpected token import

Tags: node.js, express, kue

Hi I am trying to import my class in worker and getting following error

```
(function (exports, require, module, __filename, __dirname) { import { Myclass } from '../utility/myclass';
                                                              ^^^^^^
SyntaxError: Unexpected token import
    at createScript (vm.js:53:10)
    at Object.runInThisContext (vm.js:95:10)
    at Module._compile (module.js:543:28)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:580:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:488:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:447:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:439:3)
    at Module.runMain (module.js:605:10)
    at run (bootstrap_node.js:427:7)
```

I also get error in following

```
async function getOrder() : Promise<any> {
                         ^
SyntaxError: Unexpected token :
```

I am using typescript and have included type files for kue. I run the worker from command line and it looks like it is able to understand the env... not sure whats wrong ..

Answer (score 0):

It seems you running the code without ES6 support.

You need to use [babel-cli](https://babeljs.io/docs/usage/cli/) to run this code, it will compile the code to ES6 before running it.

```
babel-node yourscript.js
```